# Start the Isotope with the defined class

Tags: jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I need to start the isotope by displaying only the div's that have the class "destaque".

At the moment, my script when loading, displays all loaded items from CMS, however if I click the filter button:

```
<li data-filter=".destaque" class="active">Todos</li>
```

It will display the items I want.

--

How start isotope displying just itens with this class div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $gridExperiencia = $('#experiencia-grid').isotope({
        filter: '.destaque',
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        transitionDuration: '0.7s',
        masonry: {
            gutter: 25
        }
    });
```

I just use **filter: '.destaque',**